# how to add scrollbar to the table body when table rows reaches more than 5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Lets say I am reading the table contents from database and printing the table rows. Sometimes I may have more than 5 rows data in the database sometimes I may have less than 5 rows data in the database.

What I want is when the table rows exceeds 5 rows it should take scrollbar, if it is less than 5 rows it should not take scrollbar.

I have gone through many websites where they fix the table body height and if the content exceeds that height it takes the scrollbar.

***So I don't want table body height to be fixed because when there is less content in the table body it will take the fixed table body size it look odd.*** Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#F0F3F4">
<div class="container">
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="well" style="background-color:#FDFEFE" ><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <p class="col-md-10">This is to test the functionality of this table</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for a test....">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:#EBF5FB">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody scrollbars="yes" id="myTable" class="dyn-height">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My table look like below image.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Scrollable tables aren't the most fun to play around with, so I've added a snippet that should get you moving along.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 if(  $('#results tr').length >= 5 ) {
      $('#myTable').addClass('add-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.add-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}

#results tr td {
   width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#F0F3F4">
<div class="container">
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="well" style="background-color:#FDFEFE" ><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <p class="col-md-10">This is to test the functionality of this table</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for a test....">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:#EBF5FB">
      <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%" height="40">
        <tr>
        <th width="33%">Firstname</th>
        <th width="33%">Lastname</th>
        <th width="33%">Email</th>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody scrollbars="yes" class="dyn-height">
      <tr>
      <td>
      <div id="myTable">
     <table width="100%" id="results">
             <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>  
     </table>  
   </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This might add a scroll bar, but it won’t make the content scrollable ... Without limiting the height of the element, this does not have the desired effect.

Comment: This isn't working for me..:( I have given both id and class name as same for tbody still not working

Comment: Is the data received in an array you can iterate over in javascript? Is the ID correct? You could use jQuery `$('#MyTableBodyID').addClass('add-scroll')`, is the class being added to the element? Have you imported the css to the relevant page?

Comment: @Testing I've added a working code snippet that should solve your issue.

Comment: @Mike Can't we add the scrollbar outside the table as it is mismatching the alignment when the browser size is small

Comment: You’ll have to look up scrollable tables, but I know first hand they’re a royal pain to deal with. Unless you add the scroll to the main <table> itself which will hide the headers when you scroll. Tables are notoriously not responsive either. So you may want to change overflow-y to just overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You have to count the number of rows then add class when the rows are greater than 5.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rowCount = $('tbody tr').length;
  if(rowCount > 5){
    console.log(rowCount);
    $('table').addClass('do-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.do-scroll{
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px; 
  display: -moz-grid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body style="background-color:#F0F3F4">
<div class="container">
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="well" style="background-color:#FDFEFE" ><br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <p class="col-md-10">This is to test the functionality of this table</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for a test....">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:#EBF5FB">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody scrollbars="yes" id="myTable" class="dyn-height">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```